# Completely Unable to Run pip on Windows 10

Tags: pip, python-3.7

I have installed Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10. The scripts folder is empty. I have all paths added to environment variable PATH. Python is working on running scripts. PIP is not yet recognized and even using python get-pip.py execution is not working.

I have read all possible fixes online but it does not help.

Anyone who can assist? Any help will be much appreciated.

C:\Program Files\Python37> python get-pip.py

Comment: _"I have read all possible fixes online but it does not help."_ Without knowing what these "all possible fixes" where, we are doomed to simply repeat what already does not work for you. Instead, give exact details.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following directory to your path.

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts
```

Then, try to download pip again. If this not working, download the get-pip.py manually and install it through the CMD as an Admin.

Here is a website: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py